# How can I test ARB transaction in sandbox account using test card in Authorize.net?

Tags: payment, sandbox, authorize.net, recurring-billing

I've subscriptions set up for Automated Recurring Billing (ARB) using customer profiles in Authorize.net.
I was able to create a subscription correctly but I'm getting transaction status as settlement error.

For transactions, I'm using test credit card provided by authorize.net and  currently, I'm testing it using sandbox account.

Can anyone please tell me how to how can I test ARB in authorize.net?

Comment: When do you see this error? When you create the subscription? Or the next day in your control panel?

Comment: I find this error when I check completed payment for each client. It says settlement error in transaction status. Is this suppose to happen when I use Test Credit Card?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can.

Just change the **Test Mode** to **Live mode** in your sandbox account.

Now you can add subscribers by test card details into the ARB transactions.